# how to click on yes / no in system configuration, does it show custom content inside?

Tags: magento2

I want to click on yes, it will show the contents and click on it to hide it
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

You can use depends tag just like follow.

```
<field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" sortOrder="20">
    <label>Enable Module</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>

<field id="upload_file_csv" translate="label" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" sortOrder="30">
    <label>Upload file csv</label>
    <depends>
        <field id="enable">1</field>
    </depends>
</field>
```

Second field depends on value of first field 1(Yes).

Comment: Please accept answer so that it may help others as well.